# Eclipse JFace TreeViewer level auto expansion doesn't work

Tags: eclipse, treeview, jface

According to the Eclipse documentation `TreeViewer.setAutoExpandLevel(3)` means that top-level elements are expanded, and their children, but not grandchildren.

I used that in my code, but after setting the input the tree is not auto-expanded, neither on OS X nor on Linux. Expanding the tree manually (via mouse) works flawlessly. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=27480

Looks like this isn't going to be changed.

Comment: For the impatient ones: use TreeViewer.expandToLevel(int level) after model modifications.